# Choose rows based on two connected column values in one statement - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

First, I'm not sure if the title represent the best of the issue. Any better suggestion is welcomed. My problem is I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+-------+-----------------+
| ID | SUPPLIER | BUYER | VALIDATION_CODE |
+----+----------+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | A        | Z     |       937886521 |
|  2 | A        | X     |       937886521 |
|  3 | B        | Z     |       145410916 |
|  4 | C        | V     |      775709785  |
+----+----------+-------+-----------------+
```

I need to show SUPPLIERS A and B which have BUYER Z, X. However, I want this condition to be **one-to-one** relationship rather than **one-to-many**. That is, for the supplier A, I want to show the column with ID: 1, 2. For the supplier B, I want to show the column 3 only. The following script will show the supplier A with all possible buyers (which I do not want):

```
SELECT *   
FROM   validation   
WHERE  supplier IN ( 'A', 'B' )   
       AND buyer IN ( 'X', 'Z');
```

This will show the following pairs: (A,Z), (A,X), (B, Z). I need to show only the following: (A,X)(B,Z) in **one statement**.

The desired result should be like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+-----------------+
| ID | SUPPLIER | BUYER | VALIDATION_CODE |
+----+----------+-------+-----------------+
|  2 | A        | X     |       937886521 |
|  3 | B        | Z     |       145410916 |
+----+----------+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you please post the desired result in table form?

Comment: The query you wrote will not produce the output you supplied for the given data. The pairs (B,X)(B,Z) does not exists in the table.

Comment: @haki Yes, you are right, I've update the question and the tables. I hope my point is clear now

Comment: Will all the records for the same supplier have the same `validation_code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the WHERE clause to filter on the desired pairs:

```
select *
from sample
where (upper(supplier),upper(buyer))
in (('A','X'),('A','Y'),('A','Z'),('B','X'),('B','Y'),('B','Z'));
```

I used the UPPER function based on your mixed case examples.

Comment: For whoever gonna check this answer later, consider that I updated the question. However, this concept is what simply solve my issue

Comment: when i use this answer ,it returns 3 rows, but hawk said that need 2 rows as result,can someone explain me how this query returns 2 rows??

Answer (score 0):

See if this what you need:

```
SELECT MAX(id),
       supplier, 
       MAX(buyer), 
       MAX(validation_code)
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM Validation
 WHERE supplier IN ( 'A', 'B' ) AND buyer IN ( 'X', 'Z')
) filtered
GROUP BY supplier;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7d7f/19)

I used `GROUP BY supplier` to *flatten* the table and included **maximum** values of `ID`, `Buyer`, and `Validation_Code`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try this:

```
SELECT id
     , supplier
     , buyer
     , validation_code 
FROM (SELECT id
             ,max(id) OVER(PARTITION BY supplier) AS maxid
             ,supplier
             ,buyer
             ,validation_code
              FROM sample) AS x
WHERE x.id=x.maxid
```

You may have a look to the results of the inner SQL statement to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select ID,SUPPLIER,BUYER,VALIDATION_CODE from
(select
t2.*,t1.counter
from
validation t2,
(select supplier,count(supplier) as counter from hatest group by supplier)t1
where 
t1.supplier = t2.supplier)t3
where t3.supplier in('A','B') and
id = case when t3.counter > 1 then 
(select max(id) from validation t4 where t4.supplier = t3.supplier) else t3.id end;
```